# Change attribute's element from another html file with javascript/php

Tags: javascript, parsing, php

I have a phtml file containing following code.

**NavigationTree.phtml :**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li id="element1">
            <a data="CercleRouge.svg" onclick="loadSynoptic()">Element Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="element2">
            <a data="CercleVert.svg" onclick="loadSynoptic()">Element Menu 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have second phtml file containing :

**SynopticView.phtml :**

```
<div>
    <img id="synoptic" src="" />
</div>
```

I want to parse the SynopticView.phtml file by clicking on the menu elements from NavigationTree.phtml and replace the src attribute value (in SynopticView.phtml) by the value of the data attribute (in NavigationTree.phtml) using the js function loadSynoptic(). My question is : how can i do that? What must i do in my js function loadSynoptic() ? Thx.

Comment: on the on click event handler you will have to first get the current object using this. then from that you get the data attribute. later use the document.getElementById to fetch the id of the img attribute of of the div for synopticview.phtml and use the inner.html on that div attribute to update the src value

Comment: Can you post response example?